# How to delete the array with index 2 in local storage?

Tags: arrays, local-storage

My local storage looks like this

```
{"data":[[0,"Post1","Text1","2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"],[1,"Post2","Text2","2016-12-20T14:00:00.000Z"]],[3,"Post3","Text3","2016-12-25T13:00:00.000Z"]]}
```

How can I delete only one item in the array?

I have tried with this, where postid is the array index I want to delete.

```
var postid = 1

var info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rp_data"));  

var obj = [];
for(var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++){ 
var data = info.data[i];
if(data === postid){
    info.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
localStorage.setItem("rp_data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

So the if part is wrong I guess!?
Any input appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE
So with this I can remove one of the posts in the array, where the first item in the array is equal to my postid, so if the postid=1 it will remove the second post in the array.

```
//var postid = $$(this).attr('data-id');
//postid=parseInt(postid)
postid=1

var info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rp_data"));  

//remove object
for(var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++){ 
var data = info.data[i][1];
myApp.alert(data);
if(i === postid){
myApp.alert(i); 
         info.data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

  localStorage.removeItem("rp_data");
  localStorage.setItem("rp_data", JSON.stringify(info));
```

So I have 1 more problems.

1. If I use postid=1 as above it works and it creates a new local storage with the right values. But if get the value from my form and then try to convert the string to a number it stops working.
   This does not work, like it is not converting the string to a number?

   var postid = $$(this).attr('data-id'); 
   postid=parseInt(postid)

   So why is this not converting it to a number?

Answer (score 0):

Since the items in the array are JSON objects, you cannot compare the object to postid. You should use indexOf. You also don't want to splice the index. This should be the object or item in this case. If you want to remove the item in the object, you would have to iterate through the object as well. So this would be a nested loop.

```
//remove object
for(var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++){ 
var data = info.data[i];
if(i === postid){
         info.data.splice(data, 1);
    }
}

//remove item in object
for(var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++){
  if(i == postid){
    for(var j = 0; j < info.data[i].length; j++){
        var item = info.data[i][j];
        info.data[i].splice(item,1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. I had to change so it removed the array , where the first item in the array was the same as posted. So now it works to delete an array. But I have 2 problems left. I will update my question, hope you can help :-)

Comment: Claes, what is 'this' in $$(this)? Are you inside of a function? Can you give me a little more detail? Then I can try and test it in the console.